# Who is Bubble referring to here?

Tags: trailer-park-boys

In S03E06 of TPB, when talking about a custom BBQ he's built, Bubbles refers to someone in the following way:

> ...red blue green *%&^*sucker*

Who is he talking about?

I'm assuming it's some Canadian or American TV personality, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He's referencing the [Red Green Show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Red_Green_Show).

> The Red Green Show is a Canadian television comedy that aired on various channels in Canada, with its ultimate home at CBC Television, and on Public Broadcasting Service (PBS) stations in the United States, from 1991 until the series finale April 7, 2006, on CBC. The Red Green Show is essentially a cross between a sitcom and a sketch comedy series, and is a parody of home improvement, do-it-yourself, fishing, and other outdoors shows (particularly The Red Fisher Show).

In particular, this is a reference to this segment:

> **Handyman Corner**
>
> Red attempted to demonstrate creative and often humorous ways to tackle relatively common tasks, such as taking out the trash or making use of derelict cars, or to **create something extravagant out of whatever he could get his hands on.** Memorable examples included a paddlewheeler made out of a van on pallets and a revolving door, **a jetpack made from two propane tanks**, a hybrid car from recycled golf carts and satellite dishes, and a kiddie ride made from a bar stool attached to the agitator of a washing machine. **Duct tape, "the handyman's secret weapon," was almost always the fastener of choice.**

Comment: "Remember, if they don't find you handsome, they'll at least find you handy" +1